# Run asp.net code in Wordpress

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, optimization

I've written some simple code in asp.net:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "30%off" Then
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com")
        Else
            MsgBox("Please Enter a Valid Coupon!")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now what I have done is from the source of the debug output i got:

```
<form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="OsC7M9VmZwGOYizZOWtmabCIp4X2NQYfYRFcdzfKSxsD49xOULNCTlEoDVRN+YXcWGszYY8WFsSxjzPjpz2y7ibXajRjMSlVqKd6QRRLU8A=" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="7ypvqvaBZUfanEsFUMFtxAPFZCwRdYQbqGVJokLWdjwcfQ7ZvJx3zMwTvTvPmbzwDzuI6vbSwPSJhS4u5RX6OZHOxyXMabjHe+TtQ//Ium5NXK/5orWrR3k5816LVHY+CBovAFHhcndnueiaWFcrxQ==" />
</div>
    <div>

    &nbsp;<span id="Label1">PROMOTION CODE :</span>
        <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" style="height:16px;width:211px;margin-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 0px" />
        <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Enter" id="Button1" style="width:101px;margin-left: 1px" />

    </div>
    </form>
```

Now what I want to do is just paste this as a snippet in Wordpress. However when I paste the code and press the submit button I get a 404 not found; is there a way out like running iframes etc?

Comment: button click code is in code-behind file that is .VB file and this file is not available. you cannot run asp.net code in wordpress, you cannot mix two different programming environments  and you need IIS to run a asp.net site.

Comment: Yes, you could use an `iframe`, although they tend to be discouraged. If I _had_ to use a .net technology for this, I would use AJAX and grab the HTML snippet asychronously - jQuery is bundled with WP and can do this for you. If you run Wordpress from Windows, I believe you can host it via IIS, and have the .net code running from the same server. Would you explain why you want to do this in .net, and not PHP?